# How to fix this code to display images thumbnails

Tags: python-3.x, pydicom

The following code is supposed to display thumbnails of different images that are available in the `\data` directory. However, something is wrong with it.

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = "data/"
file_names = [mypath+f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
number_files = len(file_names)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (40,50)) 
fig.subplots()
axes = []
for i ,file_name in  enumerate(file_names):
    dataset = pydicom.dcmread(file_name)
    axes.append(fig.add_subplot(int(math.sqrt(number_files))+1 , int(math.sqrt(number_files))+1, i+1))
    plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
```

I have the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-3ed68a41a4d3> in <module>
     10     dataset = pydicom.dcmread(file_name)
     11     axes.append(fig.add_subplot(int(math.sqrt(number_files))+1 , int(math.sqrt(number_files))+1, i+1))
---> 12     plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
     13 plt.show()

...
RuntimeError: The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. GDCM)
```

I've tried to do `!conda install -c conda-forge gdcm -y` but I've gotthe following error:

```py
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
                                                                               failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - gdcm -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Any idea how to fix the error?

Comment: There is no working conda-version for GDCM for Python 3.8 yet, AFAIK, but I don't understand why the GDCM handler is tried at all - maybe there is a failed installation of GDCM that is detected but not working. Try to uninstall GDCM completely first and check if Pillow is sufficient for your need.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to GDCM that'll be available in the next released version of pydicom is [pylibjpeg](https://github.com/pydicom/pylibjpeg) (disclosure: I'm a contributor to pydicom and author of pylibjpeg). You can use pylibjpeg with pydicom v2.0 simply by importing it before calling `Dataset.pixel_array`:

### Installation

`pip install pylibjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg`

### Usage

```py
from pydicom import dcmread
import pylibjpeg

ds = dcmread('path/to/file.dcm')
arr = ds.pixel_array
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't absolutely need python 3.8, you could try to create a new environment with a python 3.7 interpreter by using the following command line:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

You could also try to install the dependency with pip from your existing environment.